# How can I store my variable in a file?

Tags: tcl

I am using Tcl/Tk and I want to store several variables in a file. I already stored some but one resist. Could you explain me why?
Here are my procedures where my variable appears, these procedures are in three different scripts linked by a "source" declaration on the top:

In the main script

```
proc loginCreate { name } {
if {[file exists users/$name] == 1} {
    set answer [tk_dialog .dialog "Username already existing" "This username already exists. Do you want to log in as $name?" \
        question 1 Cancel "Log in"]
    if {$answer == 0} {return} else {
        loginValid $name
        set ::goOn2 1
    }
}
set ::user $name
set ::entryTestScores {"Not Taken" "Not Taken" "Not Taken" "Not Taken" "Not Taken" "Not Taken" "Not Taken" "Not Taken"\
"Not Taken" "Not Taken" "Not Taken"}
set ::testScores {"Not Taken" "Not Taken" "Not Taken" "Not Taken" "Not Taken" "Not Taken" "Not Taken" "Not Taken"\
"Not Taken" "Not Taken" "Not Taken"}
setColor khaki
onSelect 0
set ::genAvg 0
set ::goOn2 1
}
```

In another script

```
proc readUserFile { name } {
    if {[file exists users/$name] == 0} {return -1}
    set ::user $name
    set fd [open users/$name r]
    set data [split [read $fd] \n]
    close $fd
    set ::entryTestScores [lrange $data 1 $::nbTests] ;# Entry test scores stored from line 1 to line nbTest
    set ::testScores [lrange $data [expr $::nbTests+1] [expr 2*$::nbTests]] ;# Individual test scores stored from line nbTest to line 2*nbTest
    if {[llength $data]>[expr 2*$::nbTests +2] && [lindex $data [expr 2*$::nbTests +2]] != ""} { ;# Colour name stored line 2*nbTest+2
        setColor [lindex $data [expr 2*$::nbTests +2]]
    } elseif {[lindex $data [expr 2*$::nbTests +2]] == ""} {
        setColor khaki
    } else {
        setColor khaki
    }
    onSelect [lsearch $::pages [lindex $data [expr 2*$::nbTests +1]]] ;# Page active to save stored line 2*nbTest+1
    set ::genAvg [lindex $data [expr 2*$::nbTests +3]] ;# General average of individual tests stored line 2*nbTest+3
    return 0
}
```

In the third script

```
proc DisplayResults {} {
    set linetag ""
    .fr.txt configure -state normal
    if {[info exist ::user]} {
        .fr.txt insert end "The best scores of $::user are:\n"
        for {set ind 0} {$ind < $::nbTests} {incr ind} {
            .fr.txt insert end \n
            incr ind
            .fr.txt insert end "\tTest #$ind\t" $linetag
            incr ind -1
            switch [lindex $::testScores $ind] {
                "Not Taken" { .fr.txt insert end "--/10\t\t" $linetag}
                10 { .fr.txt insert end "10/10\t\t" right$linetag}
                default { .fr.txt insert end "[lindex $::testScores $ind]/10\t" $linetag}
            }
        }
        if {[lsearch $::testScores "Not Taken"] == -1} {
            set mean [expr {double(round(100*[getAvg $::testScores]))/100}] ;# return the average rounded to 2 decimals
            set ::genAvg [lreplace $::genAvg 0 0 $mean] 
            .fr.txt insert end "\n\n\tYour general average is:\n\t $mean/10\n\n"
        } else {
            .fr.txt insert end "\n\nWhen you pass all the Individual Tests, your general average will be displayed here\n\n"
        }   
    } else {
        .fr.txt insert end "You are currently running on a generic profile, please log in to remember your high scores."
    }
}
```

My variable is "genAvg". Is the only variable I cannot store in the file, the other variables (in lists) like "testScores" work perfectly. I have tryed to follow the same synthax for "genAvg" but I don't understand why it doesn't work for it.

For information, the main goal of the scripts is to test students, store theire results in files and finally compare theire general average.

**Update**

I found that by looking more carefully:

```
wm protocol . WM_DELETE_WINDOW {
    set ::goOn 1
    if {[info exists user]} {
        set fd [open users/$::user w]
        puts $fd 0
        foreach elt $::entryTestScores { puts $fd $elt }
        foreach elt $::testScores { puts $fd $elt }
        puts $fd [lindex $::pages $::page]
        puts $fd $::bgColor
        close $fd
    }
    exit
}
```

This "write" in a file isn't it?

Comment: Where in your code do you attempt to store `genAvg` in a file?

Comment: Agreed with mkrieger1. genAvg is not written anywhere, plus it is declared in the first proc as `0`, then is treated as a list in the subsequent ones. Possibly a mistake?

Comment: I don't know mkreiger1, I am continuing another people work. All that concerns the variables stored in files is here. And I tried to put {set ::genAvg $mean} but it doesn't work neither.

Comment: @PiXieBulles if you just want to write the value contained in `genAvg` in the text area, use `.fr.txt insert end "The value for genAvg is: $::genAvg"`

Comment: No Jerry, I want to put the variable in a file (where the results of the user are stored).

Comment: Please see my update 2. I hope it will do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title said **How can I store my variable in a file?**, but looking at the code, I suspect you meant **read a file and put the contents into variables**. With that in mind, I noticed an *off-by-one* error. In proc `readUserFile`, after reading the file and split the contents into a list of lines (`data`), you did not do anything to the first line (at index 0, since TCL is a zero-base-index language). The first time your script retrieves things from `data` is:

```
    set ::entryTestScores [lrange $data 1 $::nbTests] ;# Entry test scores stored from line 1 to line nbTest
```

Notice that the `lrange` command takes index 1 to `$::nbTest`. That means the data at index 0 is not used. Could this be the value for `::genAvg`? If that is the case, instead of:

```
    set ::genAvg [lindex $data [expr 2*$::nbTests +3]] ;# General average of individual tests stored line 2*nbTest+3
```

try this:

```
    set ::genAvg [lindex $data 0]
```

This is a shot in the dark since I don't see any where in the code to show the order when your script writes to the file.

## Update

I just noticed that in this line:

```
    set ::entryTestScores [lrange $data 1 $::nbTests] ;# Entry test scores stored from line 1 to line nbTest
```

The comment said:

> Entry test scores stored from line 1 to line nbTest

However, in order to get the test scores from line 1 to line `nbTests`, the command must be:

```
    set ::entryTestScores [lrange $data 0 [expr $::nbTests - 1]]
```

Also, the following lines need similar adjustments.

## Update 2

I saw in your update, there is no writing of `::genAvg`. To fix that, instead of:

```
        puts $fd $::bgColor
        close $fd
```

Do this:

```
        puts $fd $::bgColor
        puts $fd $::genAvg    ; # Insert this line
        close $fd
```

Comment: Not using the very first index was the choice of the original writter. By putting ::genAvg at index 0 don't change anything.

Comment: And, I need to add the variable to the file which contained results (in order to rank different users).

Comment: So, what does the first line contains? Also, you mentioned "**I need to add the variable to the file**", but I don't see any code to write those variables to file. You are not showing relevant code which make it hard for us to help.

Comment: The first line contains nothing, it is not in use. Even with the Updated question there is no code to write things?

Comment: I see the **write to file** code in your update. Thank you. By the way, the first line contains a zero.